# BeautifulSoup scraping from a hotel's website no return

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape hotel data from different hotel websites. I can successfully scrape from sites like Bookings.com, but I am struggling to get any output for specific hotel websites (not mass booking ones).

The code below works for mass booking sites, but when I change the URL and the div class name I am trying to scrape, I don't get any output. Am I selecting the wrong div class for the information I want, or am I not able to scrape these kinds of websites?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.128 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://bookings.guoman.com/100259?datein=06/05/2021&dateout=06/08/2021&rooms=1&adults=1&languageid=1#/accommodation/room'

response=requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")


for item in soup.select('.CardList-summary'):
    print(item.string)
```

Comment: `requests` returns HTTP results as-is. Additional requests for page resources will not be performed. It's comparable to parsing `view-source:https://bookings.guoman.com/100259?datein=06/05/2021&dateout=06/08/2021&rooms=1&adults=1&languageid=1#/accommodation/room`. The site `bookings.guoman.com` is an AngularJS app. Much of the content is generated and rendered after the initial page load. Content such as `.CardList-summary` doesn't exist in the original markup. You'll need to use a service such as Playwright or Chromium to actually render the page and interact with it.

Comment: Print the `response.text`, and you'll see that just `loading div` and `scripts` are shown. My best suggestion to you is to use `selenium` for these websites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested, you can do it in Selenium. Also, your locator was wrong, at least. The correct locator would be: `.CardList-summary.CardList-summary-multirate`.
Check this example:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://bookings.guoman.com/100259?datein=06/05/2021&dateout=06/08/2021&rooms=1&adults=1&languageid=1#/accommodation/room'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10)
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".CardList-summary-title.ng-binding")))
results= driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".CardList-summary-title.ng-binding")
for res in results:
    print(res.text)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Output:

```
Standard Sleeper Double
Standard Double Room
Standard Twin Room
Standard Twin with Tower Bridge View
Executive Double Room
Executive Twin Room
Suite Double Room
Family Room Sleeps 3
Accessible Double Room
```

Comment: If I wanted to add the price of the room to the output as well, how would I change the function to accept another selector? I assume the selector would be '.CardList-price-title.ng-binding.ng-scope', but how would I add that to the function?

Comment: Create a list and append values to it

Comment: Do you need a help with it?

Comment: I managed to do this one like you said all fine. Only issue I am having now is trying to replicate the same code for other hotel websites. I seem to always get the selector names or XPATH wrong every time somehow.

Comment: Ok, if the issue is solved, please accept/upvote. Working with other sites seems like a different question.